# Correlation controlling for group-level variable

Tags: repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, partial-correlation

I have reaction time data from a repeated measures design. Each participant completed 24 trials and gave four reactions per trial. I want to calculate two difference scores from these four raw reaction times for each combination of trial and participant and test whether these two difference scores are correlated.

However, I assume that running a simple correlation analysis might yield a spurious correlation because some participants might have generally higher difference scores than others. What would be the most appropriate way of controlling for each participant's mean difference score?

I thought about running a partial correlation using the participants' mean difference scores as the controlling variable. Alternatively I could run a multilevel model with a random intercept for each participant (but I'm wondering whether this would only control for participant in the dependent variable). I'm thankful for any advice!

Comment: How do you calculate the "difference scores"?

Comment: By subtracting one raw reaction time from another raw reaction time.

Comment: taking pairwise differences gives ${4\choose 2}=6$ difference scores...

Comment: Sorry, now I understand your question. I have two experimental factors with two levels each. I take the difference between the two levels of one factor for each level of the other factor. Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you show us a piece of your data?